# Ionic 2 native Http plugin not returning response

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using Ionic 2 [HTTP native plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/) and running http.post from a provider. The data is received from the API in the provider but does not seem to be being sent back to the page component. I get error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'this.authProvider.login(formData).then')

**PAGE: login.ts**

```
 doLogin() {

      this.spinner = 'true';

      this.authProvider.login(formData).then((result:any) => {

          if(result.status == 'isTrue') {

            this.storage.set('userId', result.userId);
            this.storage.set('userToken', result.token);
            this.storage.set('profilePic', result.profilepic);
            this.storage.set('userUsername', result.username);
            this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);

          }
          else {
            this.presentToast('Incorrect email or password, try again');
            console.log('not a user');
          }
          this.spinner = 'false';
      }, (err) => { 

      });

  }
```

**PROVIDER: authProvider**

```
  login(data) {

    if (this.platform.is('ios')) 
    {
      this.http2.post(this.apiUrl+'/api/login', data, {})
        .then((dataresult) => {

          return dataresult; // this outputs ok in console.log, but doesnt 
                                return back to page

          //console.log(dataresult);

        })
        .catch(error => {

        });

    }

  }
```

Comment: you need to return the http promise as well .. `return this.http2.post(this.apiUrl+'/api/login', data, {})`

Comment: I tried that but it doesnt return the object back to the page. Also the build fails when I add return. I also tried  return new Promise(resolve => { });

Answer (score 0):

You should have to return promise from `authProvider`,

```
return new Promise(resolve => {
  this.http2.post(this.apiUrl+'/api/login', data, {})
  .subscribe(dataresult => {
    resolve(dataresult);
  });
});
```

Comment: I have tried this and the HTTP native plugin for some reason doesnt accept .subscribe . The build fails if I use subscribe

Comment: Use HttpClient from angular, import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'

Comment: It has problems with CORS issue on API end. I cant add http://localhost:8080 to CORS headers, so I need to use native HTTP

Comment: You can handle CORS issue on server side, but for now you can install and enable Allow-Control-Allow-Origin:* plugin from chrome web store for testing purpose only. But, its not secure. By responding with Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, the requested resource allows sharing with every origin.